# using Yalantis/Koloda library to load more than just 1 UIView

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, github, uiview

So I'm using this [library](https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda)  and in the example provided only static images are used to load into each card. however I want to customize the look and feel of the each card with labels, multiples UImages etc that i will load from parse.com . How can I achieve this. the function 
func kolodaViewForCardAtIndex(koloda: KolodaView, index: UInt) -> UIView {

}

Only return UIview. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

I've done the following and it works. 
Create a custom interface (.xib) view and class (in my example its called "CustomView")

```
    func koloda(kolodaNumberOfCards koloda:KolodaView) -> UInt {
    return UInt(self.run.count)
}

func koloda(koloda: KolodaView, viewForCardAtIndex index: UInt) -> UIView {

    let cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil).first as? CustomView
    let runs = self.run[Int(index)]
    cell!.textLabel!.text = runs.type
    return cell!

}
```

Comment: Would you be able to show how this can be achieved with UITableViewCells where you assign data to `cell1` and `cell2` please.

Answer (score 2):

Data source method

```
 func kolodaViewForCardAtIndex(koloda: KolodaView, index: UInt) -> UIView
```

Takes any UIView. So just create the view you need(for example from xib) and return it in this method.