# Autolayout issues on using KOLODA library

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, ios-autolayout

Am using `KOLODA` library,and i have issues in providing more than one xibs to display the cards,In that second view(Xib) size are not fit into the koloda's first xib.how to adjust the view layout,any solutions for that is much appreciated.

NOTE:The problem here is i need multiple xib's which have different formats.

//This is my code

```
self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

NSLayoutConstraint *width = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:self
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                            multiplier:1.0
                                                              constant:0];


NSLayoutConstraint *height = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:self
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0];


NSLayoutConstraint *top = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                           relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                              toItem:self
                                                           attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                          multiplier:1.0
                                                            constant:0];


NSLayoutConstraint *leading = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:0];

[self addConstraints:@[width,height,top,leading]];
```

[image]

Comment: Need a lot more info here.  Dont talk about xibs, talk about UIViews, or UIViewControllers - what is that should appear inside what?  First UIView inside the second?  Also you need to give more code - the code here doesnt really explain much about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xaldxxwnbn1gocp/Koloda-ObjC-master%202.zip?dl=0

Comment: please check my project.

Comment: I cant go through your whole project trying to work out which nibs you are talking about etc.  Please ask your question with more information and a better code snippet.

Comment: My question is,add the multiple xib's in KOLODA library

Comment: This question here seems to be similar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32111556/using-yalantis-koloda-library-to-load-more-than-just-1-uiview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112687/discussion-between-preetha-and-luke-smith).